# How to add a File Picker plugin in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, filepicker

I am creating a Flutter project in which, I have a piece of data (JSON) that I want to Import from and Export to a location the user wants to. In order to achieve this, I require a `File Picker` plugin in Flutter. Now, I searched the `Dart Packages` repository for `"file picker"` but didn't find one.

Is there a way to get a File Picker that looks like this:

[image]

or even this...

[image]

The first screenshot is preferable for me as it allows file selection from different sources (like Drive).

Also, since I want to Export the data, I might want a `Folder Picker` too. ;)
But, if there is any other alternative to Folder Picker. I'd be happy to know...

Comment: You'd have to build your own UI, but the [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) plugin gives cross-platform access to a couple of directories. Does iOS natively have a screen similar to the first image? You could also create a plugin that uses [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've created a `file_picker` plugin some time ago in order to make it possible to pick (both on iOS and Android) absolute paths and then loaded it with Flutter.

You can check it here: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: This is nice plugin.

I have a specific requirement to allow picking Image and PDF files only. Is there a way to provide multiple whitelisted file extensions?

Comment: @MilindMevada at the moment not. You can't get multiple file extension filter at the same time, unless you use `FileType.IMAGE` or `FileType.VIDEO` or so. In this case yes. However, for other custom types. it makes it hard because I try to keep the interaction between iOS and Android as seamless as possible so the dev doesn't have to be handling himself in the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. Flutter community really appreciate the open source contributions.

Comment: Will there be a Desktop implementation of this plugin?

Comment: Yes. It’s in the upcoming features, both Desktop and Web.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo great work sir ,but it says No implementation found for method any on channel miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker

Comment: A `flutter clean` should probably fix it.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo
Thanks sir for the nice plugin, 
I used this plugin once ago, and it was working perfectly, but now it show this message

the method 'getFile' isn't defined for the type 'FilePicker'.

Comment: @NahamAl-Zuhairi you've probably updated the plugin to a later version. You've probably need to use it now as `FilePicker.platform.pickFiles()`. Check it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker).

Comment: Does Flutter really provide NO builtin file chooser dialog? Can't believe. Created a MacOS app - but can's save file generated stuff?

Comment: Note, that Flutter.dev team's FileSelector (see answer above) depends on nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I used [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) library to pick files. you can use this for pick images as well.

```
Future getPdfAndUpload(int position) async {

    File file = await FilePicker.getFile(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf','docx'], //here you can add any of extention what you need to pick
    );

    if(file != null) {

      setState(() {

          file1 = file; //file1 is a global variable which i created
     
      });

    }
  }
```

here [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) flutter library.

Comment: try this version. file_picker: ˆ1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same boat as you, haha!

I noticed `documents_picker 0.0.2`. It allows the user to pick multiple files, and it seems to fit the need!

check it out: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/documents_picker#-readme-tab-

Comment: Does it incorporate picking of folders?

Comment: Heck. It doesn't. It only allows for specific types, unfortunately. I'll keep searching @MelvinAbraham

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't tested this plugin, since I don't have my desktop right now... Does it provide an interface similar to the 1st screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better document picker. It looks like the native document picker from the Storage Access Framework, which is what you have in your picture.
[flutter_document_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_document_picker)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the [FileSelector](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector) plugin from [flutter.dev](https://pub.dev/publishers/flutter.dev/packages). Compatible with `MacOS`, `Windows` and `Web`.

From its [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector) page:

**Open a single file**

```
final typeGroup = XTypeGroup(label: 'images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png']);
final file = await openFile(acceptedTypeGroups: [typeGroup]);
```

**Open multiple files at once**

```
final typeGroup = XTypeGroup(label: 'images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png']);
final files = await openFiles(acceptedTypeGroups: [typeGroup]);
```

**Saving a file**

```
final path = await getSavePath();
final name = "hello_file_selector.txt";
final data = Uint8List.fromList("Hello World!".codeUnits);
final mimeType = "text/plain";
final file = XFile.fromData(data, name: name, mimeType: mimeType);
await file.saveTo(path);
```

**MacOS: Provide file read or/and write privileges**

On target MacOS please provide sufficient rights using Xcode:

[image: Set file read/write privileges using Xcode]

In case you don't provide file read or/and write permissions, the call to

```
final XFile? file =
    await openFile(acceptedTypeGroups: <XTypeGroup>[typeGroup]);
```

**neither shows anything not returns**.